# How to create an array of numbers from my object?

Tags: angular

I have an object with different datas, and I need to create a new array with only ID's of this object. With simple `this.object.push(data.id)` I get an array like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmajq.png) but I need to get somenthing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6i1k.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use map function from an array like below:

```js
   let object = this.data.map(r => r.id)
```

this will return your array of ids only.
output:
`['1', '2']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
let result = this.obj.map(r => r.id)
```

or

```
let result = this.obj.map(({id}) => id)
```